# Error in building android image, fails with jack server

Tags: android, linux

I am trying to build an android image, the build system by default uses jack server which keeps on failing again and again.
Can any body tell me how can i fix it.

I get the following error during build

> FAILED: setup-jack-server /bin/bash -c
> "(prebuilts/sdk/tools/jack-admin install-server
> prebuilts/sdk/tools/jack-launcher.jar
> prebuilts/sdk/tools/jack-server-4.11.ALPHA.jar  2>&1 || (exit 0) ) &&
> (JACK_SERVER_VM_ARGUMENTS="-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
> -XX:+TieredCompilation" prebuilts/sdk/tools/jack-admin start-server 2>&1 || exit 0 ) && (prebuilts/sdk/tools/jack-admin update server
> prebuilts/sdk/tools/jack-server-4.11.ALPHA.jar 4.11.ALPHA 2>&1 || exit
> 0 ) && (prebuilts/sdk/tools/jack-admin update jack
> prebuilts/sdk/tools/jacks/jack-4.32.CANDIDATE.jar 4.32.CANDIDATE ||
> exit 47 )" Writing client settings in /home/test/.jack-settings
> Installing jack server in "/home/test/.jack-server"
>
> Warning: The JKS keystore uses a proprietary format. It is recommended
> to migrate to PKCS12 which is an industry standard format using
> "keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore
> /home/test/.jack-server/server.jks -destkeystore
> /home/test/.jack-server/server.jks -deststoretype pkcs12".
>
> Warning: The JKS keystore uses a proprietary format. It is recommended
> to migrate to PKCS12 which is an industry standard format using
> "keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore
> /home/test/.jack-server/client.jks -destkeystore
> /home/test/.jack-server/client.jks -deststoretype pkcs12".
> Communication error with Jack server (58), try 'jack-diagnose' or see
> Jack server log Failed to contact Jack server: Problem reading
> /home/test/.jack-server/client.pem. Try 'jack-diagnose' Failed to
> contact Jack server: Problem reading
> /home/test/.jack-server/client.pem. Try 'jack-diagnose'

Jack server diagnose also dosen't give any usefull information

> ./prebuilts/sdk/tools/jack-diagnose    error: process ID list syntax
> error
>
> Usage:  ps [options]
>
> Try 'ps --help <simple|list|output|threads|misc|all>'   or 'ps --help
> <s|l|o|t|m|a>'  for additional help text.
>
> For more details see ps(1). Port 8077 is used by another process
> (pid=), please ensure to free the port or change port configuration in
> '/home/test/.jack-settings' and
> '/home/test/.jack-server/config.properties' error: process ID list
> syntax error
>
> Usage:  ps [options]
>
> Try 'ps --help <simple|list|output|threads|misc|all>'   or 'ps --help
> <s|l|o|t|m|a>'  for additional help text.
>
> For more details see ps(1). Port 8076 is used by another process
> (pid=), please ensure to free the port or change port configuration in
> '/home/test/.jack-settings' and
> '/home/test/.jack-server/config.properties'

and jack program throws an error for open SSL connect.

> SSL error when connecting to the Jack server, retrying with debug
>
> - Trying 127.0.0.1...
> - TCP_NODELAY set
> - Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 8076 (#0)
> - ALPN, offering h2
> - ALPN, offering http/1.1
> - successfully set certificate verify locations:
> - CAfile: /home/test/.jack-server/server.pem   CApath: /etc/ssl/certs } [5 bytes data]
> - TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1): } [512 bytes data]
> - OpenSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to localhost:8076
> - Closing connection 0

Can anybody please help me out in resolving this. I am struggling to get a clean build.

Comment: as it says, it is using a non-standard format for certificate verification (pem). openssl is unable to connect to it. Change the code to a supported standard.

Comment: Hi stark, thanks for commenting. This is a fresh piece of code, downloaded from a maintained repository. So i believe there shouldn't be a need to change the code.
If at all it is required, then what particularly I should change? can you please elaborate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When Jack diagnose gives error 35 (SSL error) the following steps worked for me

1. Edit `java.security` file under `/etc/java-8-openjdk/security/`
2. Remove TLSv1, TLSv1.1 from jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms
3. Restart the jack server:

   - `cd <aosp-home-dir>/prebuilts/sdk/tools/`
   - `./jack-admin kill-server`
   - `./jack-admin start-server`